# Driver class for Array

Tags: java, arrays

How would I develop the driver class for this code ive written ?

Array Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Array
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

private double[] array = new double[];

public void setArray(double[] arr)
{
//I must set a value for the array length. set by user.
//user must input data
}

public boolean isInIncreasingOrder()
{
//must test if input is in increasing order
}

public boolean isInDecreasingOrder()
{
//must test if input is in descending order
}

public double getTotal()
{
//must find the total of all input
//total +=total
}

public double getAverage()
{
//must calculate average
//average = total/array.length
}
}
```

I guess what I'm asking is what exactly do i call in the DriverClass and how do I do it.

Thanks

Comment: By "driver", do you mean a class that would call the various methods in Array, to verify that your implementation works?

Comment: yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to test a class is to have a "public static void main(String[] args)" method in the class itself.

In this "main" method, you first create an instance of the class, and then call the various methods in the class, and verify that they do what you expect. To make testing easier, you might want to print out a message after each call to the class under test, showing the expected result, the actual result, and a friendly "OK" or "FAIL" to let you see easily if the method did what you wanted.

Example:

```html
class MyClass {
  private int x = 0;

  public int getX() { return x;}
  public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    instance.setX(42);
    int value = instance.getX();
    System.out.print("Expected 42, got "+value);
    if (value == 42) {
      System.out.println("OK");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
  }
}
```

Once you're familiar with this approach to testing, you might look into unit test frameworks such as JUnit, which provide better ways to "assert" that a particular test is passing, and to understand the results of your testing.

Comment: could you give me an example of this ?

Comment: Added example to the answer above.